# How to get my own question migrated to an unlisted migration site?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

If I post a question and afterwards realize it's more appropriate on another site, what is the best way to get the question migrated to another site if the desired site is not listed in the migration sites list after flagging it to be closed?

I don't want to delete the post, contributing towards any negative question-ban stats & don't have the reputation to migrate it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply flag a moderator.

In the box under "in need of moderator attention" upon clicking on that option, just state that you want to migrate your question to another site and say why you think it is appropriate to do so. A moderator should soon make a decision whether the question is more suitable there or not. Before doing so, you should always check the target site's rules to ensure that it is on-topic there before it gets closed on *both sites*.

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, you're better off deleting the question and re-asking it on the new site. If you don't have lots of poor-quality questions that you've deleted (or had deleted), you're unlikely going to run into a question ban, particularly if you have *good*, upvoted questions as well.

If there's no content you feel worth preserving (existing answers, for example), just delete and repost it. If there *are* answers already, then requesting migration makes more sense... particularly as questions with answers that have positive scores *can't* be deleted.

Depending on the site, you could be waiting for hours or days for your question to be migrated instead of doing it instantly yourself. You may also have the mod decline your request. Migrations are supposed to be pretty rare and are designed to preserve great content, so the moderator may be unwilling to do the migration for you, particularly if they're not familiar with the target site's scope.

Another thing to remember is that, if your question gets closed on the site you'd rather have it on after migration, you can't even edit it in the hope it gets reopened. It will be kicked back to the originating site.